# Weird error I have no idea what to do

Tags: c++

### hw3 Deque.h

```
#include <iostream>

template <class ItemType>
struct NodeType;

template <class ItemType>
class DeQueType
{
public:
    DeQueType();
    // Class constructor.
    // Because there is a default constructor, the precondition that the
    // queue has been initialized is omitted.

    ~DeQueType();
    // Class destructor.

    void MakeEmpty();
    // Function: Initializes the queue to an empty state.
    // Post: Queue is empty.

    bool IsEmpty() const;
    // Function: Determines whether the queue is empty.
    // Post: Function value = (queue is empty)

    bool IsFull() const;
    // Function: Determines whether the queue is full.
    // Post: Function value = (queue is full)

    void EnqFront(ItemType newItem);
    // Function: Adds newItem to the front of the queue.
    // Pre:  Queue is not full.
    // Post: newItem is at the front of the queue.

    void EnqRear(ItemType newItem);
    // Function: Adds newItem to the rear of the queue.
    // Pre:  Queue is not full.
    // Post: newItem is at the rear of the queue.

    void DeqFront(ItemType& item);
    // Function: Removes front item from the queue and returns it in item.
    // Pre:  Queue is not empty.
    // Post: Front element has been removed from the queue.
    //       item is a copy of the removed element.

    void DeqRear(ItemType& item);
    // Function: Removes rear item from the queue and returns it in item.
    // Pre:  Queue is not empty.
    // Post: Rear element has been removed from the queue.
    //       item is a copy of the removed element.

    void Print( std::ostream out );
    // Function: Prints items in the deque from front to rear.  
    // Deque is printed on a single line of output with one space between each item.
    // Pre:  Deque has been initialized.
    // Post: Deque is unchanged.

    int Length();
    // Function: Returns the number of items in the deque.  
    // Pre:  Deque has been initialized.
    // Post: Function value = number of items in the deque.
    //       Deque is unchanged.

private:
    NodeType<ItemType>* dequeFront;
    NodeType<ItemType>* dequeRear;
};

#include "hw3 DeQue.cpp"
```

### hw3 Deque.cpp

```
#include <cstddef>          // For NULL

template <class ItemType>
struct NodeType
{
    ItemType info;
    NodeType* next;
};

template <class ItemType>
DeQueType<ItemType>::DeQueType()    // Class constructor.
// Post:  dequeFront and dequeRear are set to NULL.
{
    dequeFront = NULL;
    dequeRear = NULL;
}

template <class ItemType>
void DeQueType<ItemType>::MakeEmpty()
// Post: DeQueue is empty; all elements have been deallocated.
{
    NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;

    while (dequeFront != NULL)
    {
        tempPtr = dequeFront;
        dequeFront = dequeFront->next;
        delete tempPtr;
    }
    dequeRear = NULL;
}

template <class ItemType>       // Class destructor.
DeQueType<ItemType>::~DeQueType()
{
    MakeEmpty();
}

template <class ItemType>
bool DeQueType<ItemType>::IsFull() const
// Returns true if there is no room for another ItemType on the free store;
// false otherwise.
{
    NodeType<ItemType>* ptr;
    ptr = new NodeType<ItemType>;
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return true;
    else
    {
        delete ptr;
        return false;
    }
}

template <class ItemType>
bool DeQueType<ItemType>::IsEmpty() const
// Returns true if there are no elements on the DeQueue; false otherwise.
{
    return (dequeFront == NULL);
}

//template <class ItemType>
//void DeQueType<ItemType>::Enqueue(ItemType newItem)
//// Adds newItem to the rear of the DeQueue.
//// Pre:  DeQueue has been initialized and is not full.
//// Post: newItem is at rear of DeQueue.
//
//{
//    NodeType<ItemType>* newNode;
//
//    newNode = new NodeType<ItemType>;
//    newNode->info = newItem;
//    newNode->next = NULL;
//    if (dequeRear == NULL)
//        dequeFront = newNode;
//    else
//        dequeRear->next = newNode;
//    dequeRear = newNode;
//}

//template <class ItemType>
//void DeQueType<ItemType>::DeQueue(ItemType& item)
//// Removes front item from the DeQueue and returns it in item.
//// Pre:  DeQueue has been initialized and is not empty.
//// Post: Front element has been removed from DeQueue.
////       item is a copy of removed element.
//{
   /* NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;

    tempPtr = dequeFront;
    item = dequeFront->info;
    dequeFront = dequeFront->next;
    if (dequeFront == NULL)
        dequeRear = NULL;
    delete tempPtr;*/
//}

template <class ItemType>
 void EnqFront(ItemType newItem)
 // Function: Adds newItem to the front of the queue.
 // Pre:  Queue is not full.
 // Post: newItem is at the front of the queue.
{
     NodeType<ItemType>* newNode;

    newNode = new NodeType<ItemType>;
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (dequeRear == NULL)
        dequeFront = newNode;
    else
        dequeFront->next = newNode;
    dequeFront = newNode;
}


 template <class ItemType>
 void EnqRear(ItemType newItem)
 // Function: Adds newItem to the rear of the queue.
 // Pre:  Queue is not full.
 // Post: newItem is at the rear of the queue.
 {
  NodeType<ItemType>* newNode;

    newNode = new NodeType<ItemType>;
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (dequeRear == NULL)
        dequeFront = newNode;
    else
        dequeRear->next = newNode;
    dequeRear = newNode;
 }

 template <class ItemType>
 void DeqFront(ItemType& item)
// Function: Removes front item from the queue and returns it in item.
// Pre:  Queue is not empty.
// Post: Front element has been removed from the queue. 
//       item is a copy of the removed element.
 {
      NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;

    tempPtr = dequeFront;
    item = dequeFront->info;
    dequeFront = dequeFront->next;
    if (dequeFront == NULL)
        dequeRear = NULL;
    delete tempPtr;
 }

 template <class ItemType>
 void DeqRear(ItemType& item)
// Function: Removes rear item from the queue and returns it in item.
// Pre:  Queue is not empty.
// Post: Rear element has been removed from the queue. 
//       item is a copy of the removed element.
 {
     NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;

    tempPtr = dequeRear;
    item = dequeRear->info;
    dequeFront = dequeRear->next;
    if (dequeRear == NULL)
        dequeRear = NULL;
    delete tempPtr;
 }

 template <class ItemType>
 void Print( std::ostream out ) //cause of the problem
    // Function: Prints items in the deque from front to rear.  
    // Deque is printed on a single line of output with one space between each item.
    // Pre:  Deque has been initialized.
    // Post: Deque is unchanged.
{

    out << dequeFront->info << endl;
    while(dequeFront->next != NULL)
        out << dequeFront->next << endl;
 }

 template <class ItemType>
 int Length()
    // Function: Returns the number of items in the deque.  
    // Pre:  Deque has been initialized.
    // Post: Function value = number of items in the deque.
    //       Deque is unchanged.
{
    return count;
 }
```

**Error**

> `Error    1   error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream  604`

Can you help me?

Comment: For one thing, you have your includes backwards. The .cpp file should `#include "hw3 Deque.h"`, not the other way around.

Comment: @user1118321, it is a template, the way he is including is correct

Comment: Use `std::ostream& out` as an argument so you don't try to copy a stream object.

Comment: Also, the Print function is wrong. It crashes if the queue is empty (dequeFront is 0), and if the queue has more than one element, it endlessly loops printing an address since it never advances dequeFront (which it shouldn't do, of course; you'll need a copy).

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class ItemType>
void Print( std::ostream out ) //cause of the problem
```

Streams are not copyable. They are not containers; they are flows of data. Flows cannot be copied.

Take the stream by reference, instead:

```
template <class ItemType>
void Print( std::ostream& out )
```

The "weird error" is because, prior to C++11, the only way for the author of a class to actually denote that the class must not be copied, is to make its copy constructor (and assignment operator) `private`, so that you get this access error when you try anyway.

By the way, you're missing `DeQueType::` on all of those definitions, and calling a file that you `#include` ".cpp" is misleading. Yes, you need those definitions in a header, but conventionally we use ".ipp" or some other extension so as to allay confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare certain methods as members of `DeQueType` thus the linker will not be able to resolve this symbols for the following:

- `EnqFront`
- `EnqRear`
- `DeqFront`
- `DeqRear`
- `Print`
- `Length`

These methods will not be able to access private methods of `DeQueType` and in the case of `EnqFront`it will not know what to do or what to link to:

To fix add the following to the definitions:

`DeQueType<ItemType>::MethodName(args)`

BTW: Doxygen comments go above the template line like this:

```
 /** @brief Adds newItem to the front of the queue.
  * Pre:  Queue is not full.
  * Post: newItem is at the front of the queue.
  */
template <class ItemType>
 void DeQueType<ItemType>::EnqFront(ItemType newItem)
{
    // DEfinition
}
```

You should also heed @rici's advice on what could happen with the print method

Here are the methods with the scope inclusion

```
 template <class ItemType>
 void DeQueType<ItemType>::EnqRear(ItemType newItem)
 // Function: Adds newItem to the rear of the queue.
 // Pre:  Queue is not full.
 // Post: newItem is at the rear of the queue.
 {
  NodeType<ItemType>* newNode;

    newNode = new NodeType<ItemType>;
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (dequeRear == NULL)
        dequeFront = newNode;
    else
        dequeRear->next = newNode;
    dequeRear = newNode;
 }

 template <class ItemType>
 void DeQueType<ItemType>::DeqFront(ItemType& item)
// Function: Removes front item from the queue and returns it in item.
// Pre:  Queue is not empty.
// Post: Front element has been removed from the queue. 
//       item is a copy of the removed element.
 {
      NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;

    tempPtr = dequeFront;
    item = dequeFront->info;
    dequeFront = dequeFront->next;
    if (dequeFront == NULL)
        dequeRear = NULL;
    delete tempPtr;
 }

 template <class ItemType>
 void DeQueType<ItemType>::DeqRear(ItemType& item)
// Function: Removes rear item from the queue and returns it in item.
// Pre:  Queue is not empty.
// Post: Rear element has been removed from the queue. 
//       item is a copy of the removed element.
 {
     NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;

    tempPtr = dequeRear;
    item = dequeRear->info;
    dequeFront = dequeRear->next;
    if (dequeRear == NULL)
        dequeRear = NULL;
    delete tempPtr;
 }

 template <class ItemType>
 void DeQueType<ItemType>::Print( std::ostream &out ) //cause of the problem
    // Function: Prints items in the deque from front to rear.  
    // Deque is printed on a single line of output with one space between each item.
    // Pre:  Deque has been initialized.
    // Post: Deque is unchanged.
{

    out << dequeFront->info << endl;
    while(dequeFront->next != NULL)
        out << dequeFront->next << endl;
 }

 template <class ItemType>
 int DeQueType<ItemType>::Length()
    // Function: Returns the number of items in the deque.  
    // Pre:  Deque has been initialized.
    // Post: Function value = number of items in the deque.
    //       Deque is unchanged.
{
    return count;
}
```